# Don't know how to build task 'rake'

Tags: ruby, rake, ruby-1.8

I am quite new to Rails. While running the command `rake rake db:create`, I get into the following error:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'rake'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1728:in `[]'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2050:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_excep
tion_handling'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_excep
tion_handling'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
C:/Ruby187/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby187/bin/rake:23
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run `rake db:create`, not double `rake`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The answer is that simple.

Comment: I need to wait 11 minutes to do that, don't I?